# How to set nuxt anonymous middleware on homepage without export default

Tags: nuxt.js, middleware

I want to run an external script before the index page loads. I added an anonymous middleware as described in [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/middleware/#anonymous-middleware). Here is the code from the doc:

```
<script>
  export default {
    middleware({ store, redirect }) {
      // If the user is not authenticated
      if (!store.state.authenticated) {
        return redirect('/login')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The problem is that there is already a class being exported on the same page as

```
export default class Index extends Vue {
// ...
```

I am not so familiar with the project and also I am very new to nuxt. I only want to do small changes, so I do not want to touch on existing code. I tried adding both class and middleware inside `export defualt` but it did not work.

```
export default {
 Index,
 middleware ...
}
```

I tried to to export middleware without using `default` but it does not get executed in this way.

I do not want to create a common middleware and execute it when `route` is the index page as there are many different names and paths for the index page because of the multiple language selection options on the websiite.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember the name of the package, but it's basically a way of using types (without Typescript).
Check the `package.json` to find the name of the package.

It *should* not be super different IMO

```html
<script>
export default class Index extends Vue {
  middleware({ store, redirect }) {
    // If the user is not authenticated
    if (!store.state.authenticated) {
      return redirect('/login')
    }
  }
  ...
}
</script>
```

---

#### Update

It's either:

- [vue-class-component](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component) for Vue
- [nuxt-property-decorator](https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-property-decorator/) for Nuxt